# VS Console application Update Model from Database

Tags: visual-studio-2015, console-application, ef-database-first

I have a model (.edmx) (database first) in my console application (VS 2015) I added a new column to my table (SQL Server 2012) and selected "Update model from database..." menu option from the model browser but now my code does not compile or more pertinent is my model classes are not being updated. I read else where you need to Run Custom Tool however this is not doing anything for me. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else. After spending an hour on it. I ended up deleting all the generated classes under my Model.tt file (made a back up just in case - perhaps I could have just deleted only the object I changed who knows). I ran the "Run Custom Tool" option again and it regenerated the classes this time with the new field - hooray!! Then to add my annoyance it still didn't work. Fortunately I had the thought of mind to close Visual Studio and re-open my solution and recompiled (ignored the warning - something about a file/folder not in a trusted location) and then ran and it worked and even the warning disappeared! My goodness is all I have to say.